# TFS 2010 workflow transition not working for an user

Tags: tfs

In my TFS workflow configuration I have the following transition:

```
<Transition from="Implemented" to="Awaiting Validation" for="[Global]\Deploy Team">
  <REASONS>
    <DEFAULTREASON value="Awaiting validation by the team" />
  </REASONS>
</Transition>
```

This is the only configuration for this transition.

In [Global]\Deploy Team, which, in my case is Name_Of_Team_Project_Collection\Deploy Team, I have one group and several users.

In this group ([Name_Of_Team_Project]\Mobile) I have 6 windows users. One, and only one, of this users, can't do this transition.

We tried from his PC, from another PC and from Web Version. None of these has worked.

This user is in 2 TFS groups: [Global]\Deploy Team and [Name_Of_Team_Project]\Mobile.

Any ideas why this user can't do this transition?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It should say [Project]\Deploy Team if the group the user is in is project level

Comment: Hi Mike, this configuration is available for all projects, it's easier to configure the transition for global group. Right? Thank you.

Comment: I'm just saying that the permissions need to be at the project level for project and global for global.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.

Once I had all transition configuration and user permissions correctly configured, all I need to do was clear the TFS cache on client machine.

To do this, I used this script in a .bat file:

```
 cd "%localappdata%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache\" 
 for /d %%a in (*_https) do rmdir /s /q %%a
```

Note that this script can change depending on your TFS version and configuration. For more details, visit [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsalm/archive/2013/12/17/how-to-clear-the-tfs-cache-on-client-machines.aspx).

I need to thank a Microsoft colleague.